# jdk vulnerability displaying in containerd overlay snapshot

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd, crictl

Our Platform team is running security scan behind and displaying the vulnerability as java-1.8.0-openjdk. This directory was displaying under `var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots`.

Is there any way we can know from which image this snapshot was created and the complete Dockerfile.

Tried below containerd cli commands and doesnot show any output.

`ctr container list`

`ctr snapshot ls`